# Linear mapping on direct sum of two Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

We define $H$ and $K$ to be Hilbert spaces and the direct sum of $H\oplus K$ is the vector space $H\times K$ with the inner product $\langle (x,y) | (x',y') \rangle := \langle x | x' \rangle_H+\langle y | y' \rangle_K$. Now we let $T\in B(H)$ and $S\in B(K)$. We shall show that the formula $(T\oplus S)(p,q)=(Tp,Sq)$ defines a linear map $T\oplus S:H\oplus K\rightarrow H\oplus K$.

---

Here is my work which I am not sure if its correct. If not, I would appreciate help. Here it goes: We have
\begin{align*}
(T\oplus S)((p_1,q_1)+\alpha (p_2,q_2))&=(T\oplus S)(p_1+\alpha p_2,q_1+\alpha q_2)\\
&=(T\oplus S)(p_1,q_1)+\alpha (T\oplus S)(p_2,q_2)
\end{align*}

Are the above correct?

---

Further I have to show that $T\oplus S$ is bounded and also compute its norm in terms of norms of $T$ and $S$. Also I tried but I'm not sure if it is correct as well. We have $||T\oplus S(p,q)||\leq C||(p,q)||$ and where $C>0$. So,
\begin{align*}
||T\oplus S||:=||Tp+Sq||\leq||Tp||+||Sq||=C||(Tp,Sq)||.
\end{align*}
I am also need to compute the norms of $T$ and $S$.

Anyway I would really like to get help here. I want to understand this so if anyone can help me then I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

Some remarks:

In your work to show linearity: After the second '=': where are $T$ and $S$ gone?

Concerning your computation for the boundedness: What is $C$? Can your specify the value? Also: From which space does $Tp + Sq$ come from? Does it even make sense in your setting?

Comment: Hello and welcome to this platform. 
Yea, I discussed this problem with a friend as well and we can see that this might be wrong with the $S$ and $T$ gone. 

Do you have any ideas in order to solve this problem correct?

Comment: Try to apply the definition of $T \oplus S$, then both should stay. You can then use linearity of both of them.

Comment: I edited my post now. Does it make sense? Is it correct do you think?